# App is not asking for internet permission at installation

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have an Android app written by Xamarin, and it works perfectly fine when debugging.

But when I want to release it, my *.apk installer does not ask for INTERNET permission, therefore my app crashes whenever it requires connection, which is almost in every activity since it's an online app.

I have added the permission in my manifest file, but for some reason, the app only asks for Reading and Writing data from SD card permission and totally ignores internet permission.

Here is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="ComicCity.ComicCity" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="preferExternal">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DELETE_CACHE_FILES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<application android:label="ComicCity" android:icon="@drawable/CCicon"></application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what about the behavior of xamarin, but in android there is no need to ask for internet permission since it is not a dangerous permission. The Storage permissions are dangerous and they should be prompted to the user to be approved. see doc: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html#normal-dangerous

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Internet is in the normal permissions list and thus you will not get prompted as it is auto-granted

> If an app declares in its manifest that it needs a normal permission, the system automatically grants the app that permission at install time. The system does not prompt the user to grant normal permissions, and users cannot revoke these permissions.

Re: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/normal-permissions.html

Comment: Thanks for the info. You're right, apparently Internet is working and some other stuff is causing the crash.
also my app doesn't show any toast message on release mode. so I think there are a bunch of permissions that I need maybe? 
Or is it even permission related? If u don't have a permission set on your app, does it cause crash?